# Can I have 2 different Egress from AeronCluster?

Tags: java, udp, aeron

Can I have 2 different Egress from AeronCluster?

Answer (score 2):

Aeron Cluster can only have a single ingress and egress channel.  However, you can create additional publications within a ClusteredService, e.g:

```
public class FooService implements ClusteredService
{
    private Publication publication;
    private DirectBuffer someMessage;

    public void onStart(final Cluster cluster, final Image snapshotImage)
    {
        publication = cluster.aeron().addPublication("aeron:udp?endpoint=somewhere.com:2020", 10001);
    }

    public void onSessionMessage(
        final ClientSession session,
        final long timestamp,
        final DirectBuffer buffer,
        final int offset,
        final int length,
        final Header header)
    {
        publication.offer(someMessage);
    }
```

However, when doing this you need to decide if you want only the leader to publish or all nodes and how you would potentially deal with duplicated messages.

Comment: I mean AeronClient, Can I subscribe to two broadcast channels use one client

Comment: If so, please can you update the question so that the intention of your question is obvious.  Also I'm not sure what you mean by a broadcast channel.  That is not an Aeron concept.